# how to set the date time to today in jquery ui Datepicker as default

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(function () {
            $(".datepicker").datepicker({
                dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy",
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

I used the above code to show date in datepicker but the the date is set jan 2001. how do I set the DateTime to today as default in above jquery. before i put the jquery in editor templates it worked fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be the default behavior according to [jQuery UI documentation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#option-defaultDate). When the `defaultDate` option is `null` as it is by default, today's date should be highlighted on first opening. Perhaps your system time is incorrect? Here's a [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/full/tFnBa) where I tried it and it seemed to be showing today's date by default.

Comment: Try getting the current date from javascript, like `alert(new Date())`. If it shows the right time, you can add `defaultDate: new Date()` to Datepicker options and see if that helps.

Comment: alert shows the current date time just fine. but the defaultDate: new Date() shows no change in my code

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go to current date in jQuery DatePicker, you can apply it on any textfield like this:

```
$('input.youTextFieldClass').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy', 
                                     changeMonth: true,
                                     changeYear: true,
                                     yearRange: '-70:+10',
                                     constrainInput: false,
                                     duration: '',
                                     gotoCurrent: true});
```